# Google OCR Bounding Poly

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

Hi I am having trouble understanding what a bounding poly, is in the Google Cloud OCR system, I understand that it is a box around the detected text. So something like

```
   *description: "The"
bounding_poly {
  vertices {
    x: 204
    y: 132
  }
  vertices {
    x: 267
    y: 135
  }
  vertices {
    x: 265
    y: 171
  }
  vertices {
    x: 202
    y: 168
  }
}
     description: "fresh"
bounding_poly {
  vertices {
    x: 278
    y: 140
  }
  vertices {
    x: 349
    y: 144
  }
  vertices {
    x: 347
    y: 185
  }
  vertices {
    x: 276
    y: 181
  }*
```

Are the x and y coordinates the corners of each box, in java how would I detect if texts are on the same line. Are they're any libraries to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that you can refer to this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383178), approaching text alignment from within [DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/fulltext-annotations#annotating_an_image_using_document_text_ocr) method and getting `fullTextAnnotation` structured response with Page, Block, etc. parameters that you can then compare. Wouldn't this be a kind of interest?

Answer (score 0):

as we see bounding poly which gives a result vertices four line to plot box for recognized text from an image . if we want bounding box coordination from a given 4 line from **single** **word** 1st  'x' 2nd 'y',3rd 'x' , 4th 'y'